# How to change the syntax highlighting in PyCharm with Python 3.5 to Python 2.7

Tags: python, pycharm

I have installed Python 2.7, and highlights PyCharm string `import Tkinter as tk` but acceptable for Python 3.5:

`Python version 3.5 does not have module Tkinter less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Enable this inspection if you need your code to be compatible with a range of Python versions (for example, if you're building a library). The range of Python versions with which the code needs to be compatible can be specified in the inspection settings.`

How do I report PyCharm, I'm working with Python 2.7, but not with Python 3.5?

Comment: Set python2.7 interpreter as __Project Interpreter__

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company

Answer (score 3):

Project interpreter might be set correctly already. It seems that here the highlighting of code compatibility is meant. This can be changed as the following:

In `Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Python` and check `"Code compatibility inspection"`. In there you can choose the Python version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to **File -> Settings -> Project Interpreter** and enter path to your Python 2.7.

Visit [Configuring Python Interpreter for a Project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.2/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html) for complete tutorial.